How to throw custom exception in spring boot for METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED 405 error?
This is the method I wrote for exception
@ExceptionHandler(value = HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
public @ResponseBody ErrorResponse handleRequestMethodNotSupportedException(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex){
    return new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.value(), ex.getMessage());
}

Now I am not able to figure out where and how to throw this exception?
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<SupplierOutputDTO>> getAllSuppliers() throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getAllSuppliers(), HttpStatus.OK);
}

this is my get method in controller so in postman if instead of get if I send post request then 405 error will be shown so how can I handle this. I tried using throws exception in method signature but it is not working

Handling METHOD NOT ALLOWED 405 is not required explicitly. The framework handles that for you.
@GetMapping("/hello") maps a GET call to the endpoint /hello. So in case you send a POST request to "/hello", it would automatically throw a 405 for you. So get the HTTP verb mappings correctly and let the framework take care of the 405 for you.
Exception handler is mostly used to handle custom exceptions and send back modified responses with proper messages for clients to understand better, what went wrong. Usually, any exception at application level - GET /products/1, where /products/:id API does exists, you need to handle the exception and throw back a 404 along with some custom message that product id 1 is not available, or 403, user is not allowed to view the data.
